# pm2, node, instances and ports

Tags: node.js, pm2

Sorry if this question is to 'newbie' but I can't see how to do it / how it works.

1/ I am creating an API using node.js, API serving some front apps

2/ To get it robust I use pm2 (great product), having nginx as proxy, fine

3/ But how could I handle multiple instance of my node.js api ? I see the 'cluter mode', fine, but what's happening while my node.js is listening on a single port (8080 for instance)  ? If I configure 4 process / instances, they just can't all listen on the same port ah the same time ? ... so : do pm2 dispatch the calls between the instances (so acting as a kind of proxy indeed).

Any clue will be appreciated, how does it work ?

Greg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Node in cluster mode creates one master and then spawns worker process which share TCP connection so basically load is distributed among workers.

Here is a beautiful article which elaborates both pm2 and node cluster -

https://getstream.io/blog/running-pm2-node-js-in-production-environments/

Hope it helps.

Comment: but how could I handle session variables between threads ? Is that handled automatically or do I have to use something to handle it (memcahe maybe?)

Comment: Hi, I answer my question : I have to handle sessions by myself, mode does not handle session sharing, so identification, info between pages ... hs to be handled manualy between calls

Comment: Yes, one has to handle shared variables from own implementation. I normally prefer a combo of Redis and Mongo. It depends from use case to use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage load using nginx also. here is the documentation for nginx [load balance](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/http-load-balancer/)

after that you can run app with specific port using environment variable from .env file and access it like this way. ex: process.env.PORT

after that run app using pm2 this way

```
PORT=5003 pm2 start routes.js --name app5003
PORT=5002 pm2 start routes.js --name app5002
PORT=5004 pm2 start routes.js --name app5004
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your answers, 
So, from all the tips you gave me :

- I have to handle by myself sessions and variables between threads,
- pm2 cluster mode is the right way
- pm2 will dispatch calls between instances, let's say in a round robin way

Case closed, again thank you very much for all your tips and answers yu provided, you save me a great bunch of time.